# Check if condition is true and if so add value to another column in sql

Tags: sql

I have a postgres table that looks like this:

```
A      B
5      4     
10     10
13     15
100    250
20     Null
```

Using SQL, I would like to check whether the value in column `A` is *larger* than the value in column `B` and if so, then add a 1 to the column `True`. If the value in column `A` is *smaller* or *equal* to the value in column `B` or if column `B` contains a [NULL] value, I would like to add a 1 to the column `False`, like so:

```
A      B       True   False
5      4       1      0 
10     10      0      1 
13     15      0      1 
100    25      1      0 
20     [NULL]  0      1
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when A > B then 1 else 0 end) as true_col,
       (case when A > B then 0 else 1 end) as false_col
from t;
```